# Aggregation of DataFrame in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sum, aggregation

I have DataFrame like below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"ID" : ["1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "1"],
                   "status" : ["ac", "not", "not", "ac", np.NaN, "ac", "oth"]})
```

And I need to build DataFrame with columns like below:

1. NumberAcc - Number of ID with status = "ac"
2. NumberNaN - Number of ID with status = NanN (missing -> np.nan)
3. NumberOther - Number of ID with staatus other than "ac" or np.nan (means "not" or "oth")

Could you help me to build DF like below?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a conditional mask to replace anything which is not ac or `np.nan` as `Other` and `groupby.value_counts` , then unstack and format with `add_prefix`

```
u = df['status'].where(df['status'].eq("ac")|df['status'].isna(),"Other")

out = (u.groupby(df['ID']).value_counts(dropna=False).unstack(fill_value=0)
        .add_prefix("Number_").reset_index().rename_axis(None,axis=1))
```

Or;

```
a = pd.Series(np.select([df['status'].eq("ac"),df['status'].isna()],
              ['acc',np.nan],'other'))
out = (a.groupby(df['ID']).value_counts(dropna=True).unstack(fill_value=0)
        .add_prefix("Numnber_").reset_index())
```

---

```
print(out)

  ID  Number_nan  Number_Other  Number_ac
0  1           0             3          1
1  2           1             0          2
```

A similar logic but with crosstab as suggested by @Shubham:

```
u = df['status'].where(df['status'].eq("ac")|df['status'].isna(),"Other")
out = (pd.crosstab(df['ID'],u.fillna("NAN"),dropna=False)
   .add_prefix("Number_").rename_axis(None).reset_index())
```

Comment: anky, great, but can i add a list of column in .eq() ? for instance if i would like to add there more than only "ac" for example .eq("ac" ,"bc") and so on ?

Comment: @jack55 yes try `isin` insead of `eq` for multiple values: `u = 
 df['status'].where(df['status'].isin(["ac","bc"])|df['status'].isna(),"Other")`

Comment: @anky May be try `crosstab` like `pd.crosstab(df['ID'], df['status'].fillna('NaN'))`..

Comment: GREAT! thank you I gave you best answer! :)

Comment: this is incredible, how do you figure this out anky? guess i'm not so faimilar with unstack function

Comment: @MaxYarmolinsky thank you. with a little bit practise here on SO :-) you may be intersted in the docs : https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html :-) Happy coding

Comment: @ShubhamSharma thats would work but what if we have multiple sucn columns  not only one (`not`) to be added to `oth` then it becomes cumbersome

Answer (score 2):

You could create the columns via [assign](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html), before grouping on the 'ID' and summing:

```
     (df.assign(NumberAcc=df.status.eq("ac"),
                NumberNaN=df.status.isna(),
                NumberOther=lambda df: ~(df.NumberAcc | df.NumberNaN))
        .groupby("ID")
        .sum())

    NumberAcc   NumberNaN   NumberOther
ID          
1       1           0           3
2       2           1           0
```